# Apache HTTP connection with Android 6.0 (Marshmallow)

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, apache-httpclient-4.x, android-6.0-marshmallow

Is there is any way to include the Apache library directly in Gradle to make it work with Android 6.0 ?

I've tried to include the libraries like that:

```
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
```

And Android Studio couldn't manage to find the following import:

```
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthenticationException;
import org.apache.http.auth.Credentials;
import org.apache.http.auth.MalformedChallengeException;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.impl.auth.DigestScheme;
```

Comment: try to clean and rebuild

Answer (score 57, accepted):

[This page](https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client) discusses the removal of the Apache HTTP classes, and it suggests a workaround as well:

> To continue using the Apache HTTP APIs, you must first declare the following compile-time dependency in your build.gradle file:
>
> ```
>    android {
>        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
>    }
> ```

In my case Android Studio still complained that it couldn't find these classes, but the app did build and run.

The page does recommend you move to [HttpURLConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html), though.

Comment: @Hrk but it's far better to update your code to latest Android standards

Comment: @Nepster Try to do Http digest over okhttp with latest android standard, still waiting for a good implementation :(

Answer (score 1):

According to the API 22-23 diff changes, the org.apache.http.* packages have been removed as of Android 6.0 (Marshmallow) API Level 23.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/23/changes.html

via : http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2015/08/m-developer-preview-3-final-sdk.html