# ParseApacheHttpClient issue with Android Marshmallow: can't find referenced method SSLSocketFactory.getHttpSocketFactory

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm working on Android Marshmallow support in my Android app but I have dependencies which are using the deprecated [Apache HTTP client](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client) (including Parse).

As recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32075449/5489877), I've added:

```
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
```

in my app/build.gradle but I can't still compile an apk:

```
:app:compileFreeStoreDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileRetrolambdaFreeStoreDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileFreeStoreDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:proguardFreeStoreDebug
Note: there were 7 duplicate class definitions.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#duplicateclass)
Warning: com.parse.ParseApacheHttpClient: can't find referenced method 'org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory getHttpSocketFactory(int,android.net.SSLSessionCache)' in library class android.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory
Warning: there were 1 unresolved references to library class members.
         You probably need to update the library versions.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedlibraryclassmember)
Exception while processing task
java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
    at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:473)
    at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:233)
    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:98)
    at proguard.gradle.ProGuardTask.proguard(ProGuardTask.java:1074)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.AndroidProGuardTask.doMinification(AndroidProGuardTask.java:139)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.AndroidProGuardTask$1.run(AndroidProGuardTask.java:115)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.Job.runTask(Job.java:48)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.SimpleWorkQueue$EmptyThreadContext.runTask(SimpleWorkQueue.java:41)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:227)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you have the `useLibrary` statement in the right spot? I'm using that for legacy apache support and everything is building and working fine. It should be in your module `.gradle` file within the Android block.

Comment: were you able to find the solution for this ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This issue is solved in 2 parts:

1. adding back the legacy Apache library
2. updating ProGuard configuration for Parse.com

I'm going to address both parts below for completeness.

For those looking for the *quick fix*, **the solution is to add the following line to your ProGuard configuation file**:

```
-dontwarn android.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory
```

---

### 1 - Apache Library

Android-M removes support for the Apache HTTP library. As mentioned in the question, the fix is to use the legacy support JAR by updating your build.gradle. Here is the code with a bit more context:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    ....
}
```

---

### 2 - Update ProGuard Configuration

The actual error comes from ProGuard, when it is trying to process Parse.com.

```
Warning: com.parse.ParseApacheHttpClient: 
can't find referenced method 'org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory getHttpSocketFactory(int,android.net.SSLSessionCache)' 
in library class android.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory
```

Parse is now open source, so checking the issues gives this page on GitHub:

- [Issue with android M compilesdkversion 23 #231](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-Android/issues/231)

The discussion explains that this is just a ProGuard config item, and can be safely fixed by updating your config as per the related issue:

- [Update proguard-rules.pro for android-23 #234](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-Android/pull/234/files)

Here is the change (line 3 fixes our issue, line 4 fixes related issue):

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes Signature
-dontwarn android.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory
-dontwarn android.app.Notification
-dontwarn com.squareup.**
-dontwarn okio.**
```

As explained in [this comment](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-Android/pull/234#issuecomment-154162553), it is safe to ignore the warnings since those classes are only ever used on Android versions that still contain the mentioned classes.